# Formula Field Help or Alternative - Automated Solution

Tags: formula, formula-field, error-messages, compile-error

Management asked my co-worker to create a formula field they can use for reporting.

He doesn't have a stack exchange account (and doesn't want to make one just yet /shrug) so I'm posting in his behalf.

The Blanks_Contract_Stage_to_Install__c field is a formula field that we are referencing inside of this, a new formula field. Management was wanting a formula field because formula fields always have current values without needing to go and trigger an update for each record. But if we need to some kind of timed automation to produce a similar result is not out of the question.

We need to reduce the compile size of this formula. Currently it compiles to 5,983 characters. Either that or we need something that can be run on a timer, hopefully that wouldn't require an Apex solution. (We can code it, but would like to not have to if possible).

```
CASE(TEXT(Territory_Picklist__c),
     "Buda",
     IF(Blanks_Contract_Stage_to_Install__c < 50, "Expected",

     IF(Blanks_Contract_Stage_to_Install__c < 80, "Past Expected", "Out of Bounds")),


 "Albuquerque",

     IF(Blanks_Contract_Stage_to_Install__c < 45, "Expected",

     IF(Blanks_Contract_Stage_to_Install__c < 75, "Past Expected", "Out of Bounds")),


  "Charleston",

     IF(Blanks_Contract_Stage_to_Install__c < 55, "Expected",

     IF(Blanks_Contract_Stage_to_Install__c < 90, "Past Expected", "Out of Bounds")),

  "Columbia",

     IF(Blanks_Contract_Stage_to_Install__c < 55, "Expected",

     IF(Blanks_Contract_Stage_to_Install__c < 90, "Past Expected", "Out of Bounds")),

  "Connecticut",

     IF(Blanks_Contract_Stage_to_Install__c < 40, "Expected",

     IF(Blanks_Contract_Stage_to_Install__c < 60, "Past Expected", "Out of Bounds")),

  "Pueblo",

     IF(Blanks_Contract_Stage_to_Install__c < 35, "Expected",

     IF(Blanks_Contract_Stage_to_Install__c < 45, "Past Expected", "Out of Bounds")),

     IF(Blanks_Contract_Stage_to_Install__c < 30, "Expected",

     IF(Blanks_Contract_Stage_to_Install__c < 60, "Past Expected", "Out of Bounds")) )
```

The formula in the referenced field Blanks_Contract_Stage_to_Install__c looks like this:

```
   BLANKVALUE(Installation__r.Solar_Install_Date__c, TODAY()) - Financing__r.Contract_Stage_Complete__c
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Use custom labels you can reduce size and use flows if you dont want to write code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following formula should help:

```
IF(Blanks_Contract_Stage_to_Install__c < 

 CASE(TEXT(Territory_Picklist__c),
  "Buda",50,
  "Albuquerque",45,
  "Charleston",55,
  "Columbia",55,
  "Connecticut",40,
  "Pueblo",35,
 ,30),

"Expected",

IF(Blanks_Contract_Stage_to_Install__c < 
 CASE(TEXT(Territory_Picklist__c),
  "Buda",80,
  "Albuquerque",75,
  "Charleston",90,
  "Columbia",90,
  "Connecticut",60,
  "Pueblo",45,
 ,60),

"Past Expected",
"Out of Bounds")
)
```

Comment: This did exactly what we needed. I didn't know you could condense a CASE function that way in a Salesforce formula. The compile size was right around 1600. Thanks! I/we learned something very valuable from this response.

Comment: Glad to help. We all are learning something everyday.